# Sequelize - multi-condition queries

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize to query a PostGIS database and return user records based on geographic proximity. I want to exclude the current user from the search results, but I can't figure out the proper syntax to add multiple conditions to this particular kind of search.

As it stands, the query is

```
models.Geometry.findAll({
        where: models.sequelize.where(
            models.sequelize.fn(
                'ST_Distance_Sphere',
                models.sequelize.col('the_geom'),
                models.sequelize.fn(
                    'ST_GEOMFROMTEXT',
                    'POINT(' + row.dataValues.longitude + ' ' + row.dataValues.latitude + ')', 4326
                )
            ),
            '<=',
            radius
        )
    })
```

I'd like to add

```
where: {
     UserId: {
         $not: currentUser.id
     }
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the Sequelize docs with an example... the closest I got was

```
Post.findAll({
     where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('char_length', sequelize.col('status')), 6)
});
```

but this is not really any different than my current situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign the `models.sequelize.where` function value to some attribute in the `where` object - this attribute will not be used as a lookup field

```js
models.Geometry.findAll({
    where: {
        stDistanceSphere: models.sequelize.where(
            models.sequelize.fn(
                'ST_Distance_Sphere',
                models.sequelize.col('the_geom'),
                models.sequelize.fn(
                    'ST_GEOMFROMTEXT',
                    'POINT(' + row.dataValues.longitude + ' ' + row.dataValues.latitude + ')', 4326
                )
            ),
            '<=',
            radius
        ),
        UserId: { $not: currentUser.id }
    }
})
```

Or you can use the `sequelize.and()` function to construct `AND` query

```js
models.Geometry.findAll({
    where: models.sequelize.and(
        models.sequelize.where(
            models.sequelize.fn(
                'ST_Distance_Sphere',
                models.sequelize.col('the_geom'),
                models.sequelize.fn(
                    'ST_GEOMFROMTEXT',
                    'POINT(' + row.dataValues.longitude + ' ' + row.dataValues.latitude + ')', 4326
                )
            ),
            '<=',
            radius
        ),
        { UserId: { $not: currentUser.id } }
    )
})
```